# Lookup on limited baseEnum

Tags: axapta, dynamics-ax-2012-r2

I have a table `set` which contains two columns: `setId` and `value`.
`setId` is referenced to a baseEnum `setBE`, containing the values `A`, `B`, `C` and `D`.

Data in this table:

```
A, 10
B, 20
D, 25
```

Another table setExt contains two columns: `setId` and `extension`.
setId should be referenced to the baseEnum `setBE`, but only values existing in first table `set` should be able to choose, in this case:

```
A
B
D
```

Problem is ( imho ) the fact that the first table refers to a `baseEnum` and not to an `EDT`, correct? Any possibilities to achieve this?

Comment: yes, the problem is that you are using an enum for an ID (why?!)

Comment: To limit the possible values. I tried to limit the BE-elements using SysFormEnumComboBox::newParameters(), and it works if there is a combobox on the form, but not in the grid from a datasource :/